# Basic buffer overflow tutorial

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

I'm learning about basic buffer overflows, and I have the following C code:

```
int your_fcn()
{
    char buffer[4];
    int *ret;

    ret = buffer + 8;
    (*ret) += 16;

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int mine = 0;
    int yours = 0;

    yours = your_fcn();
    mine = yours + 1;

    if(mine > yours)
        printf("You lost!\n");
    else
        printf("You won!\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My goal is to bypass the line `mine = yours + 1;`, skip straight to the `if` statement comparison, so I can "win". `main()` cannot be touched, only `your_fcn()` can.

My approach is to override the return address with a buffer overflow. So in this case, I identified that the return address should be `8` bytes away from `buffer`, since buffer is `4` bytes and `EBP` is `4` bytes. I then used `gdb` to identify that the line I want to jump to is `16` bytes away from the function call. Here is the result from gdb:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000054a <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x0000054e <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x00000551 <+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x00000554 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x00000555 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00000557 <+13>:    push   %ebx
   0x00000558 <+14>:    push   %ecx
   0x00000559 <+15>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0000055c <+18>:    call   0x420 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x00000561 <+23>:    add    $0x1a77,%ebx
   0x00000567 <+29>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0000056e <+36>:    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x00000575 <+43>:    call   0x51d <your_fcn>
   0x0000057a <+48>:    mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x0000057d <+51>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x00000580 <+54>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000583 <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x00000586 <+60>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00000589 <+63>:    cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x0000058c <+66>:    jle    0x5a2 <main+88>
   0x0000058e <+68>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x00000591 <+71>:    lea    -0x1988(%ebx),%eax
```

I see the line `0x00000575 <+43>:    call   0x51d <your_fcn>` and `0x00000583 <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)` are four lines away from each other, which tells me I should offset `ret` by `16` bytes. But the address from gdb says something different. That is, the function call starts on `0x00000575` and the line I want to jump to is on `0x00000583`, which means that they are `15` bytes away?

Either way, whether I use `16` bytes or `15` bytes, I get a `segmentation fault` error and I still "lose".

**Question**: What am I doing wrong? Why don't the address given in gdb go by 4 bytes at a time and what's actually going on here. How can I correctly jump to the line I want?

---

**Clarification**: This is being done on a x32 machine on a VM running linux Ubuntu. I'm compiling with the command `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 -g guesser.c -o guesser.o`, which turns stack protector off and forces x32 compilation.

---

gdb of `your_fcn()` as requested:

```
(gdb) disassemble your_fcn
Dump of assembler code for function your_fcn:
   0x0000051d <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0000051e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00000520 <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x00000523 <+6>: call   0x5c3 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x00000528 <+11>:    add    $0x1ab0,%eax
   0x0000052d <+16>:    lea    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x00000530 <+19>:    add    $0x8,%eax
   0x00000533 <+22>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x00000536 <+25>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x00000539 <+28>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x0000053b <+30>:    lea    0xc(%eax),%edx
   0x0000053e <+33>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x00000541 <+36>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x00000543 <+38>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000548 <+43>:    leave  
   0x00000549 <+44>:    ret
```

Comment: All bets are off after `(*ret) += 16;` ?

Comment: all bets are off in `your_fcn()` if you are asking what can be changed.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856942/basic-buffer-overflow-tutorial#comment84717444_48856942), and ever earlier `buffer + 8;` is UB.

Comment: @chux yes I saw that.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen added the question

Comment: Since you’re playing with assembler, you should diagnose which CPU you are targetting and whether you are building 32-but or 64-but, and probably which o/s since the layouts can be different.  If you include `-fomit -frame-pointer` and you’re working with GCC, you may get a different result.  And a good optimizing compiler night spot the UB and arrange to reformat your disk before you do any real damage — or maybe you’ll be lucky and your compiler will let your hard drive live to see another day

Comment: *"Why don't the address given in gdb go by 4 bytes at a time?"* because many processors have variable length instructions?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler and @Weather Vane. I added a clarification that gives the exact environment this is in.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the recent OP's comment was to you too.

Comment: The `call` itself is not relevant since you are overwriting the return address. Hence, you should calculate the offset relative to `0x0000057a <+48>`. Assuming you have found the correct place on the stack, that should mean an offset of `9`.

Comment: The first assembly instruction after the function call saves the return value from the function call into `yours`. So your intended approach to change the return address to skip ahead in the calling function won't work, because `yours` will never be assigned a value.

Comment: @prl well isn't that the bread and butter of a buffer overflow attack? to try and edit `EIP` value so that it jumps to the code you want? What do you mean it's saved in `yours`?

Comment: @Jester, assuming everything else is correct, I changed the line `(*ret) += 16;` to `(*ret) += 9;`, it's still a segmentation fault and I still lose :(

Comment: You need to post disassembly of `your_func`. Presumably your offset of `ret = buffer + 8;` is wrong.

Comment: @Jester posted gdb of `your_fcn()`

Comment: After the function `your_fcn` returns, the value it returns is saved into `yours`. When you change the return address, this assignment is skipped. The question says you want to bypass the line `mine = yours + 1`. I was simply pointing out that you cannot bypass that line without also bypassing the assignment to `yours`.

Comment: The compiler allocates `ret` at ebp-4 and `buffer` at ebp-8, so the return address is at buffer+12.

Comment: Thinking in terms of skipping C source lines by skipping asm instructions only works for debug builds, i.e. `gcc -O0`.  Just so you realize that this is the "training wheels" version so there are lots of places you can jump to where execution will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 has variable length instructions, so you cannot simply count instructions and multiply by 4. Since you have the output from gdb, trust it to determine the address of each instruction.

The return address from the function is the address *after* the call instruction. In the code shown, this would be main+48.

The `if` statement starts at main+60, not main+57. The instruction at main+57 stores `yours+1` into `mine`. So to adjust the return address to return to the if statement, you should add 12 (that is, 60 - 48).

Doing that skips the assignments to both `yours` and `mine`. Since they are both initialized to 0, it will print "You won".

Comment: make sense now. I also realized I overwrote the return address with wrong syntax, it should be `ret = &buffer[4] + 8;` instead of `ret = buffer + 8;`. thanks!